# Creating centroid from line while keeping attributes of line using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pointgeometry

I have created a centroid from a line I want the centroid to be created with attributes of the line. By executing the following code I get this result:

```
import arcpy 
input_fc = 'Export_GC_a_integrer'

output_fc =r"Export_GC_a_integrer_XY_toto"
fields = ["OBJECTID", "CODE_SITE", "SHAPE@XY"]

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, fields)
centroid_coords = []
for feature in cursor:
    centroid_coords.append(feature[2])
 
point = arcpy.Point()
pointGeometryList = []

for pt in centroid_coords:
    point.X = pt[0]
    point.Y = pt[1]
    pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
    projectedPointGeometry = pointGeometry.projectAs("102582")
    pointGeometryList.append(projectedPointGeometry)
 arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometryList, output_fc

arcpy.AddField_management(output_fc, "OBJECTID", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(output_fc, "CODE_SITE", "TEXT")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, fields) as sCur : 
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_fc, ["OBJECTID", "CODE_SITE"] ) as iCur : 
        for row in sCur : 
            iCur.insertCursor(row)
```

Result :

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would like to have the fields: OBJECTID IDCODE SHAPE_len in the created point. I have created this point from this table

[image]

Comment: The easiest is to spatial join the line fields to the centroids, if possible

Comment: how can I do this from the fields I have? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: do you have an Advanced licence? use Feature to Point tool https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm it will create a centroid point an maintain attributes.

Comment: You can easily use the polyline feature class as a template to create a point feature class, then a nested DA SearchCursor within a DA InsertCursor to copy the table, replacing the polyline with a point, which can be done at any license level (in 10 lines of code).

Comment: thanks for the hint i did the manipulation i update the code so you can see the result. i have two lines instead of only one.

Comment: @Clubdebambos no i don't have advanced licence.